# Why does $f$ and $f′$ non-trivial factor?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. Why do $f$ and its derivative $f′$ share a non-trivial common factor?

Comment: It doesn't, unless $f$ has multiple roots in $\Bbb C$

Comment: And by "multiple roots" he means "roots of multiplicity at least 2".

Comment: Are you asking "**When** does $f$ and $f'$ have a non-trivial common factor?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is true in general, for polynomials over arbitrary fields:

> $f$ and $f'$ have a nontrivial common factor iff $f$ has a nontrivial square factor.

Let $p$ be an *irreducible* common factor of $f$ and $f'$. Then $f=pg$ and $f'=ph$ and so $ph=f'=pg'+p'g$. This implies that $p$ divides $p'g$. Since $p$ cannot divide $p'$ because of degrees, $p$ must divide $g$ and so $p^2$ divides $f$.

If $f=g^2h$ then $f'=2gg'h+g^2h'=g(2g'h+gh')$ and $g$ is a common factor of $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: Let  $f(x,y) $ be polynomial. what about $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}$?

Comment: @Undersky, my answer works in that case, if you look at the polynomials as being polynomials in $y$, but there may be important details, since $K[x]$ is not a field. If you need more, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

$f$ and $f'$ do not share a non-trivial common factor, as the example $f(x)=x$ clearly shows.

Comment: How can we prove in general case?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x)$ has no root in $\mathbb{R}$ then we have nothing to prove..

Suppose $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ and $g(a)\neq 0$..

Then, $f'(x)=g(x)+(x-a)g'(x)$.. For this, $f'(a)=g(a)\neq 0$.

Suppose $f(x)=(x-a)^kg(x)$ for some $k\geq 2$ then you compute $f' $ and see what happens..